# AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'wtiter'

Tags: python, csv

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib.request
url = 'https://www.sports.ru/epl/table/'
import urllib.request

def get_html(url):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    return response.read()

def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    teams = []

    for row in soup.select('tbody > tr'):
        cols = row.select('td')

        teams.append({
            'Место': cols[0].text,
            'Команда': [name.text for name in row.select('a[class=name]')],
            'Матчи': cols[2].text,
            'Выйгрыши': cols[3].text,
            'Ничьи': cols[4].text,
            'Поражения': cols[5].text,
            'Забито': cols[6].text,
            'Прорущено': cols[7].text,
            'Очки': cols[8].text
        })

    return teams

def save(teams,path):
    with open(path,'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.wtiter(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(('Место','Команда','Матчи','Выйгрыши','Ничьи','Поражения','Забито','Пропущено','Очки'))

        for team in teams:
            writer.writerow((team['Место'], ', '.join(team['Команда']),team['Матчи'],team['Выйгрыши'],team['Ничьи'],team['Поражения'],team['Забито'],team['Прорущено'],team['Очки']))

def main():

    teams = []

    save(teams,'апл.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

35 строка.
Большого опыта работы с библиотекой csv не имею.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не думаю что у этого модуля есть метод `wtiter`, вот `writer` - вполне возможно.

Comment: Блин зрение подвело глупая ошибка.